# Post user entered message on Facebook timeline using Open graph API

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-opengraph

I have a custom UI for posting a URL and image with user entered message on Facebook. I have not submitted my App for review yet to Facebook.
But I am still able to post URL and image on my timeline since I have developer account.

I am using below code to post.
I am following Facebook's guide of not pre-filling the data. User is typing the message here. But I could not figure out how to post message.
Below is my code.

```
let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject.init(properties: [
        "og:type": "website",
        "og:title": milestone.fbOgTitle,
        "og:description": milestone.fbOgText,
        "og:url": milestone.shareUrl,
        "og:image": milestone.fbOgImage
        ])

    // Create an action
    let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction.init()
    action.actionType = "books.reads"
    action.setObject(object, forKey: "books:book")

    // Create the content

    let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent.init()
    content.action = action
    content.previewPropertyName = "books:book"
    FBSDKShareAPI.share(with: content, delegate: self as! FBSDKSharingDelegate)
```

Comment: make sure you know the difference between sharing an url (which does not need authorization) and posting an image or a message (which does need authorization with the publish_actions permission). read about the /user/feed post endpoint in the api reference.

Comment: Yes I am posting image with URL and I am going to submit publish_actions permission on Facebook developers. @luschn

Comment: i am not sure if there even is a message in open graph actions, the api reference says there is no such thing. if you want to post a user message, use the /user/feed post endpoint instead of open graph actions.

Comment: How can I post user message with image and a URL on Facebook @luschn

Comment: check out the api reference about that